# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:994 (add_subdirectory)

Tags: python, git, cmake, openpose

I'm trying to install the **Python API** in order to link **Openpose** to **Touchdesigner** but when I want to turn on the Python flag inside CMake I get this error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:994 (add_subdirectory):
>     The source directory
>
> C:/Users/user/Desktop/openpose/openpose-master/3rdparty/pybind11
>
> does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.
>
> CMake Error at python/openpose/CMakeLists.txt:6 (pybind11_add_module):
>     Unknown CMake command "pybind11_add_module".
>
> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>
> See also "C:/Users/user/Desktop/openpose/openpose-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Comment: Activating my prophecy crystal... You probably need to run `git submodule init && git submodule update`, or check out something into that directory.

Comment: I'm a newbie, how can I do? I installed Git Bash and pasted "git submodule init" but it gaves me an error. Sorry and thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: `pybind11` directory most probably has to contain complete `pybind11` module. You can clone or download it from github. It contains missing `CMakeLists.txt` file together with other files.